# Number of token exceeds while using Langchain code understanding

Tags: openai-api, langchain

I am using LangChain code understanding. I am using a whole repo but I got token limit exceeded error. The example in official page was about the twitter algorithm which is also have lots of file. I tried to ask specific question with the filename but it is still exceeding the prompt. Are there any suggestion for that?

I tried to use LangChain code understanding. I was expecting answer about my question but I got token limit error.